# AVD do not work on Android Studio - statvfs snapshot error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Im setting up a new virtual android device on the AVD, I have Arch Linux operating system. This is a Pixel 3a XL model with Pie Android. I have all of the default settings of the AVD. When I try to turn on the device it prints out the following error:

```
Emulator: statvfs('/home/nadav/.android/avd/Pixel_3a_XL_API_28.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory
```

When I go to that folder I have a file named ram.img.dirty.

I have seen some suggestions online on what to do but none of them worked.

- I have tried to rename the file to ram.img.
- I have tried to change the boot to a cold boot.
- I have tried to delete everyting under the snapshots folder.
- I have tried to delete the device and install it from the beginning.

still none of those suggestions work.

I hope you can help me please, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit on this same problem after update. Today I have installed 3.6 Canary 12 and it is working fine. I am running Debian 10.